# Remove item from filtered array in vue

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js

Right now I filter an array with companies. The filter returns only the companies which have active on true. That is working but.. When I try to remove an item with splice from the filtered array it's not working.

The filter:

```
computed: {
    activeCompanies() {
        return this.companies.filter((company) => {
            return company.active;
        });
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div v-for="(company, index) in activeCompanies">
    <h2>{{ company.name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ company.description }}</p>
    <p>{{ company.id }}</p>

    <a @click="archiveCompany(company.id, index)">Archive</a>
</div>
```

When I try to splice from the activeCompanies array:

```
archiveCompany(id, index) {

    axios.put('/api/companies/archive/' + id)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    this.activeCompanies.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
<div v-for="company in activeCompanies" :key="company.id">
    <h2>{{ company.name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ company.description }}</p>
    <p>{{ company.id }}</p>

    <a @click="archiveCompany(company.id)">Archive</a>
</div>


archiveCompany(id) {

    axios.put('/api/companies/archive/' + id)
        .then(response => {
            this.companies = this.companies.filter(x => x.id !== id)
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

> 1. Use company.id as key and not index
> 2. Remove item by id and not by index
> 3. Use arrow function response =>, so you can use this inside
> 4. Only remove an item when your request finished successfully

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you don't understand some parts feel free to ask.

Comment: And also feel free to mark this answer as solution if it works for you :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

you should use:
this. companies = this.companies.filter(x => x.id !== id)